# How to Fix IE6 Bug - position: absolute; & overflow: auto;

Tags: asp.net, overflow, position, internet-explorer-6

I made a Editable Combo box using the following code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server" Width="75px" Style="position: absolute;" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" Width="95px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And I create a javascript for onChange of the dropdown and show the selected text in textbox.
My issue is when I running on IE6 the textbox is not showing and i read from Google that it is an issue with IE6. Is there any method to work the position: absolute;?

I have also a gridview which is inside a  and I set the overflow: auto; of  to show the scrollbars. Its is also not working in IE6?

Please give me some solutions to overcome these?

Comment: One answer would be stop using IE6 since it's a pile of sh@t, but I guess you have to support it. I know that feeling well - I've worked on many SharePoint solutions where we had to support IE6 even though it actually extended the project's length. Grrrr.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try setting an explicit width on your TextBox's parent element (the element that you've positioned relatively): I've found in the past that any *left*, *top*, *right* or *bottom* values for positioning elements absolutely have been way off in IE 6 unless I've set the positioned parent's width.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: not a solution, but a workaround**

Use the [almighty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471597/is-jquery-always-the-answer) JQuery [UI Autocomplete Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) instead (View the comboBox demo).
You gain multi-browser support and your solution look less hacky.

[image]